# CSS - Repeating Header/Footer Image - Tied to content, but not above bottom of screen

Tags: html, css, background

I wanted to have a site that has a repeating image across the top and bottom of my webpage.

I am able to have my background repeating all across he top of the page/body/screen, but I can't get the bottom background to work.

For the bottom, I'm trying to get it to repeat along the x axis similar to the top, but IF the content doesn't fill the window/screen, I want the image to be tied to the bottom of the screen. IF the content is larger than the window/screen, I want the footer to be tied to the content (off screen until you scroll down to see it.)

When I tried, I could only get the footer to display in a div and so it wouldn't repeat to the edge of the screen, nor would it display under the content (only in the footer div) This is becoming a nightmare!

Is this possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**But I want the following to have the content (header / content and footer text etc) to be centered and fixed width. Below is along the lines of what I have so far.**

http://jsfiddle.net/kuhfkhr4/

```
    html,
    body {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            height:100%;
        background-image: url("/images/backgrounds/light-top-small-2014.jpg");
        background-position: top center;
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
    }
    #wrapper {
            min-height:100%;
            position:relative;
    }
    #header {
            padding:10px;

    }
    #content {
            padding:10px;
            padding-bottom:180px;  
    }
    #footer {
        background-image: url("/images/backgrounds/light-bottom-small-2014.jpg");
        background-position: bottom center;
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
            width:100%;
            height:180px;
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0;
            left:0;

    }
```

**EDIT**
**Also notice how the bottom image is cut off. I want the footer text to start about 150px from the bottom, but I want the image to extend the full 300px height that it is. The div that it is in unfortunately cuts it off. Ideas?**

Comment: Can you show us your HTML and CSS?

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle.

Comment: Code added and I included the jsfiddle...

Comment: Some how... I got it working at http://jsfiddle.net/martindevnow/y0r7n7ve/1/ but I cannot get it to work on my site. http://brushpoint.martindevnow.com/
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kuhfkhr4/2/)

Add this class.

```
#header{text-align:center;}
#footer{text-align:center;}
```